What is a vertex attribute array?
I am learning OpenGL, and as I understand, attribute pointers are used to access data from VBOs.
Given that a vertex attribute array stores the state (enabled or disabled) for each attribute, and each attribute is associated with a single attribute pointer each draw call, I fail to see why the function is called glEnableVertexAttribArray(index) and not glEnableVertexAttrib(index).
What is a vertex attribute array?
